# Slide div after previous transaction of div is accomplished

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've created a category section just like a banner slider. When I click on the category (Electronic, Men & Women) the sub-category comes below the above sub-category as show in this **[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/vnfew20j/)**.
Later I tried to close the previous sub-category i.e suppose Electronic sub category was `display:block` and when I click on Men Category, Sub category of Electronic will slide to the left and from right Men category will slide in but problem here is transaction should be done smoothly where as Men sub category shows up before Electronic sub category is totally slide out to the left. I need to do same smooth transaction for women subcategory as well stuck here in previous please do have a look at it I am really confused about where exactly I am going wrong. Other **[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/vnfew20j/2/)** showing the second scenario I tried to do.

Codes and Snippet of 2nd **[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/vnfew20j/2/)** given below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#categorywrapsElectronics").click(function() {

        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionright').val() };
        var secondoption = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionleft').val() };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 500;
        var quickduration = 300;
        var lateduration = 1000;

        if ($('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, secondoption, duration);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, options, duration);
        }
    });








    $("#categorywrapsMen").click(function() {

        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionright').val() };
        var secondoption = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionleft').val() };
        
        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 500;
        var quickduration = 300;
        var lateduration = 1000;

        if ($('#subcategorywrapsMen').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, secondoption, duration);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').css('display') == 'block')
            {
                $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, secondoption, quickduration);
                $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, options, lateduration);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, options, duration);
            }
        }
    });






    $("#categorywrapsWomen").click(function() {

        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionright').val() };
        var secondoption = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionleft').val() };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 500;
        var quickduration = 300;
        var lateduration = 1000;

        if($('#subcategorywrapsWomen').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, secondoption, duration);
        }
        else
        {
            if($('#subcategorywrapsMen').css('display') == 'block')
            {
                $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, secondoption, quickduration);
                $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, options, lateduration);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, options, duration);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.catheadwraps {
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000080;
    height: 8%;
    width: 12.2%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.subcategorywraps {
    display: none;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="categorywrapsElectronics" class="catheadwraps">
    Electronics
</div>
<div id="categorywrapsMen" class="catheadwraps">
    Men
</div>
<div id="categorywrapsWomen" class="catheadwraps">
    Women
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="right" class="hiddendirectionright">
<input type="hidden" value="left" class="hiddendirectionleft">
<div id="subcategorywrapsElectronics" class="subcategorywraps">
    Electronics
</div>
<div id="subcategorywrapsMen" class="subcategorywraps">
    Men
</div>
<div id="subcategorywrapsWomen" class="subcategorywraps">
    Women
</div>
```

**UPDATED CODE, SNIPPET &** **[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/vnfew20j/4/)**

This Update has feature that enables you to move to women category when electronic category is open already and visa versa, but problem is the same yet transaction are smooth but starts together.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#categorywrapsElectronics").click(function() {

        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionright').val() };
        var secondoption = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionleft').val() };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 500;
        var quickduration = 300;
        var lateduration = 1000;

        if ($('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, secondoption, duration);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($('#subcategorywrapsMen').css('display') == 'block')
            {
                $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, options, quickduration);
                $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, secondoption, lateduration);
            }
            else
            {
                if ($('#subcategorywrapsWomen').css('display') == 'block') 
                {
                    $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, options, quickduration);
                    $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, secondoption, lateduration);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, options, duration);
                }
            }

        }
    });








    $("#categorywrapsMen").click(function() {

        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionright').val() };
        var secondoption = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionleft').val() };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 500;
        var quickduration = 300;
        var lateduration = 1000;

        if ($('#subcategorywrapsMen').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, secondoption, duration);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').css('display') == 'block')
            {
                $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, secondoption, quickduration);
                $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, options, lateduration);
            }
            else
            {
                if ($('#subcategorywrapsWomen').css('display') == 'block')
                {
                    $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, options, quickduration);
                $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, secondoption, lateduration);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, options, duration);
                }
            }
        }
    });






    $("#categorywrapsWomen").click(function() {

        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionright').val() };
        var secondoption = { direction: $('.hiddendirectionleft').val() };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 500;
        var quickduration = 300;
        var lateduration = 1000;

        if ($('#subcategorywrapsWomen').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, secondoption, duration);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($('#subcategorywrapsMen').css('display') == 'block')
            {
                $('#subcategorywrapsMen').toggle(effect, secondoption, quickduration);
                $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, options, lateduration);
            }
            else
            {
                if ($('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').css('display') == 'block') 
                {
                    $('#subcategorywrapsElectronics').toggle(effect, secondoption, quickduration);
                    $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, options, lateduration);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#subcategorywrapsWomen').toggle(effect, options, duration);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.catheadwraps
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000080;
    height: 8%;
    width: 12.2%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.subcategorywraps
{
    display: none;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="categorywrapsElectronics" class="catheadwraps">
    Electronics
</div>
<div id="categorywrapsMen" class="catheadwraps">
    Men
</div>
<div id="categorywrapsWomen" class="catheadwraps">
    Women
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="right" class="hiddendirectionright">
<input type="hidden" value="left" class="hiddendirectionleft">
<div id="subcategorywrapsElectronics" class="subcategorywraps">
    Electronics
</div>
<div id="subcategorywrapsMen" class="subcategorywraps">
    Men
</div>
<div id="subcategorywrapsWomen" class="subcategorywraps">
    Women
</div>
```